# How to give input variables in K means clustering in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a data set of 29 variables. From this data set I want to use specific 9 variables to make 6 different K means clusters. How to specify relevant variables while making cluster in R . Should I just filter out the data first and use that data to make the cluster ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a matrix with n-rows (number of samples) and 29-columns (number of variables for each sample). Now, what you need to do is "feature selection" where each variable is a feature. Using feature selection you will be able to identify features which contribute to the variability in your data. Though, it would be nice if you can inform why you need only 9 features. Anyway, regarding feature selection this might be helpful:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/introduction-to-feature-selection-for-bioinformaticians-using-r-correlation-matrix-filters-pca-backward-selection/

If the ultimate objective is to cluster the data, then I would propose that you rather do a PCA first and try to reduce the dimensionality of the data and later you can do clustering. Again, it would be nice if you inform why you need only 6 clusters.

Comment: Thanks @Manish . Thing is that we are doing the  clustering using one tool Statistica and now I am trying to simulate the results using R. I already know that I need to make total 6 clusters(Already defined) and I also know which variables are important for clustering. I just want to know how to do variables selection while making clusters.

Comment: From my understanding, variable selection and clustering are two independent tasks. So, I would suggest to not mix them.

Answer (score 0):

Build a subset data frame that *only* contains those features that you want to use.

Then run k-means on these columns only.

You can trivially map back the indexes to the original (full) data.

Comment: Thanks Anony, that's what I am doing too right now. I just wanted to confirm if it's the right approach.